# Ubuntu, program currently not installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I have Ubuntu 10.04.4.

I downloaded and installed scala (.tgz archive), unpacked into /opt, set rights for read and execute in `bin` for all users. Also updated PATH in `/etc/environment`

When I run program just with `scala` command, though name is autocompleted it is not run:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user# scala
  The program 'scala' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
  apt-get install scala
```

But if I use full path to executable it works.

Executables from scala/bin is in PATH (autocomplete works).
What am I doing wrong?

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user# which scala
root@ubuntu:/home/user# whereis scala
scala: /opt/scala-2.9.2/bin/scala /opt/scala-2.9.2/bin/scala.bat /opt/scala/bin/scala /opt/scala/bin/scala.bat
root@ubuntu:/home/user# echo $PATH
${SCALA_HOME}/bin:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
root@ubuntu:/home/user# echo $SCALA_HOME
/opt/scala

root@ubuntu:/home/user# cat /etc/environment 
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"
SCALA_HOME="/opt/scala"
PATH=${SCALA_HOME}/bin:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Comment: What is the output of `which scala`?

Comment: empty, added some info into post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PATH statement looks wrong, given your output:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user# echo $PATH
${SCALA_HOME}/bin:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

The `${SCALA_HOME}` should have expanded out there.

What did you add to your `/etc/environment`?

Update:

Ah, OK.  /etc/environment is not processed by shell, so variable expansions, like you are trying in your PATH, will not work there.  It only expects key-value pairs.

Put your updated PATH into `/etc/profile` or something similar.  You should be able to keep your $SCALA_HOME and $JAVA_HOME settings in `/etc/environment`, though, but the variable expansion will not work in there.

(A similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/78856/referencing-environment-variables-in-etc-environment)

Comment: added at the end of the post

Comment: @confused-demon I've updated my Answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are right. It was a sneaky stab from behind. Who would have known that such "sophisticated" ability as variable expansion was considered unnecessary when setting system wide variables... Crap :)

Comment: Personally, I've always used /etc/profile for this sort of thing, but I'm a holdover from the old days (and I tend to use RHEL/CentOS) before they invented fancy things like /etc/environment.

Comment: I wanted it to be in all users' profiles, that's why I used `/etc/environment`. In redhat I used just `/etc/bashrc` for this purpose and though it would work in ubuntu also.

Comment: Yeah, I think Ubuntu actually recommends using /etc/profile, but the neglect to mention the important fact that it doesn't work like you think it will.  For RHEL, /etc/profile is preferred for env variables. In fact, /etc/bashrc actually mentions that in the second line of comments!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `/opt/scala/bin` to your `$PATH`. Judging from the path, your `Scala` installation was probably compiled from source rather than installed with Ubuntu's package management (`apt`/`dpkg`).

Comment: PATH is above, and scala is not compiled there, just extracted (it is java app), though manually but not via apt-get